# Can you send messages to Facebook users from external XMPP servers?

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger, xmpp, instant-messaging

I don't have Facebook account, but I'd like to message some of their users. I did read someplace that Facebook Messenger is using XMPP, so it might be possible to send messages to their servers from external Jabber servers, but how to get user JIDs?

Or is it not possible at all?

Comment: Related: [Facebook XMPP Chat API send Message PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15813542/facebook-xmpp-chat-api-send-message-php)

Comment: Well - **I** don't have facebook account. So I can't connect to their server.

Comment: so you can't access their API either I would assume... Hmm- if I can think of solutions for how you might build a way to connect as a non-user but you would have to have an account to make it (I believe)

Comment: my point is: if they are using xmpp for their messanger, it should be available for outside users too, shouldn't it? I mean - sure, they could have closed the server to no outbound connections to other servers, but ... and this is why i asked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They only support client to server XMPP, not server to server XMPP.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat/:

> Facebook Chat should be compatible with every XMPP client, but is not a full XMPP server.

So you can use any XMPP client for the Facebook Chat, but you can only chat with other Facebook users.

Which is a pity. Welcome to the 90s.